# "Full Calendar" in PrimeNG can not work well on iOS Device

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2, primeng

I tried to deploy the schedule ( Prime NG ) to the iOS Device : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

I see that I can't scroll the time into the schedule. When I adjust the time into the schedule table, it always show add date dialog. I only can scroll the timeline. I can't scroll to adjust the time.

Do you have any ideas in my cases ?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly, I found out the issues. If I want to move or adjust the time, I only keep the finger longer on the blue section ( time has just added ) and the draggable section will be shown. There are some different behavior from PrimeNG. But the issue is resolved.

Thanks,